# how do print a portion of a page that gets new divs with inputs inside them when u press button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am working on a digital reference where there is an inputs form that when submitted is put into newly made divs with JavaScript. Each time you submit a form it is put into a new div which I called "newReferenceDiv" in the JS file below. I am facing issues when I am trying to print these new divs/references. I found a way to take just the first reference for printing, but unfortunately, I haven't found a way to print all the references/divs. I would really appreciate any help. After you look at my JS code, please keep in mind that my code to print the first reference does not include the inputs inside the reference itself, just their values. This is because I don't want the edit and delete buttons to show when I need to print the references.
Thanks in advance and I apologize for the long question and long code snippet.
I will be happy to provide other information or code should you need it.

**My JavaScript code**

```js
//assigning variables
const form = document.querySelector("#form");
const input = document.querySelector("#input-bar");
const list = document.querySelector("#list");

//form event listener
form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //new-reference-div
  const newReferenceDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newReferenceDiv.classList.add("reference");
  list.appendChild(newReferenceDiv);

  //new-reference-name
  const nameInput = document.querySelector("#name");
  const newReferenceName = document.createElement("input");
  newReferenceName.type = "text";
  newReferenceName.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  newReferenceName.value = nameInput.value;
  newReferenceDiv.appendChild(newReferenceName);
  nameInput.value = "";

  //new-reference-number
  const numberInput = document.querySelector("#phone");
  const newReferenceNumber = document.createElement("input");
  newReferenceNumber.type = "number";
  newReferenceNumber.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  newReferenceNumber.value = numberInput.value;
  newReferenceDiv.appendChild(newReferenceNumber);
  numberInput.value = "";

  //new-reference-check-in
  const checkInInput = document.querySelector("#check-in");
  const newReferenceCheckIn = document.createElement("input");
  newReferenceCheckIn.type = "date";
  newReferenceCheckIn.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  newReferenceCheckIn.value = checkInInput.value;
  newReferenceDiv.appendChild(newReferenceCheckIn);
  checkInInput.value = "";

  //new-reference-price-quotation
  const PQ_Input = document.querySelector("#P_Q");
  const newReferencePQ = document.createElement("input");
  newReferencePQ.type = "text";
  newReferencePQ.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  newReferencePQ.value = PQ_Input.value;
  newReferenceDiv.appendChild(newReferencePQ);
  PQ_Input.value = "";

  //new-reference-device-type
  const deviceTypeInput = document.querySelector("#device-type");
  const newReferenceDeviceType = document.createElement("input");
  newReferenceDeviceType.type = "text";
  newReferenceDeviceType.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  newReferenceDeviceType.value = deviceTypeInput.value;
  newReferenceDiv.appendChild(newReferenceDeviceType);
  deviceTypeInput.value = "";

  //new-reference-batch-number
  const batchNumberInput = document.querySelector("#batch-number");
  const newReferenceBatchNumber = document.createElement("input");
  newReferenceBatchNumber.type = "number";
  newReferenceBatchNumber.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  newReferenceBatchNumber.value = batchNumberInput.value;
  newReferenceDiv.appendChild(newReferenceBatchNumber);
  batchNumberInput.value = "";

  //line-break-function
  const lineBreak = () => {
    const br = document.createElement("br");
    newReferenceDiv.appendChild(br);
  };

  lineBreak();

  //new-reference-damage
  const damageInput = document.querySelector("#damage");
  const newReferenceDamage = document.createElement("textarea");
  newReferenceDamage.rows = "2";
  newReferenceDamage.cols = "145";
  newReferenceDamage.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  newReferenceDamage.classList.add("damage");
  newReferenceDamage.value = damageInput.value;
  newReferenceDiv.appendChild(newReferenceDamage);
  damageInput.value = "";

  lineBreak();

  //new-reference-button-edit
  const edit = document.createElement("button");
  edit.classList.add("edit");
  edit.innerText = "Edit";
  newReferenceDiv.appendChild(edit);
  
  //new-reference-button-delete
  const remove = document.createElement("button");
  remove.classList.add("delete");
  remove.innerText = "Delete";
  newReferenceDiv.appendChild(remove);
  
  const newReferencesArray = [
    newReferenceName,
    newReferenceNumber,
    newReferenceCheckIn,
    newReferencePQ,
    newReferenceDeviceType,
    newReferenceBatchNumber,
    newReferenceDamage,
  ];
  
  //giving the delete button action
  remove.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    list.removeChild(newReferenceDiv);
  });

  //giving the edit button action
  edit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (edit.innerText == "Edit") {
      edit.innerText = "Save";
      for (let i = 0; i < newReferencesArray.length; i++) {
        newReferencesArray[i].removeAttribute("readonly");
        newReferencesArray[i].focus();
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < newReferencesArray.length; i++) {
        edit.innerText = "Edit";
        newReferencesArray[i].setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
      }
    }
  });


  //printing references
  const printBtn = document.querySelector("#print");
  printBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let printwin = window.open("");
    for (let newRef of newReferencesArray) {
      console.log(newRef.value);
      printwin.document.write(newRef.value);
      printwin.print();
    }
  });
  

});
```

**Here is my HTML file-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Digital Reference</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Assets/D-logo.jpg">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/digital-reference/digital-reference.css">
    </link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Bootstrap.css/bootstrap.css">
    </link>
</head>

<body>
    <video autoplay muted loop class="background-video">
        <source src="/Assets/background-clip-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <header>
        <h1 id="header-h1" class="text-center">DABBAS</h1>
    </header>
    
    <section>
        <div id="form-div">
            <form id="form" action="/nowhere" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div id="inputs-div">
                    <div class="d-block">
                        <label for="name">Full name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" class="inputs">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-block">
                        <label for="phone">Phone No:</label>
                        <input type="number" id="phone" class="inputs">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-block">
                        <label for="check-in">Check-in:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="check-in" class="inputs">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-block">
                        <label for="P_Q">Price Quotation:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="P_Q" class="inputs"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-block">
                        <label for="device-type">Device type:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="device-type" class="inputs">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-block">
                        <label for="batch-number">Batch number:</label>
                        <input type="number" id="batch-number" class="inputs">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-block">
                        <label for="damage">Damage:</label><br>
                        <textarea id="damage" rows="3" cols="40" class="inputs"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Add">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <h2 id="references-heading" class="text-center text-secondary"><i>References</i></h2>
        <!-- <input type="button" value="Print" id="print" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary d-block"> -->
        <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center mb-4">   
        <button id="print" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">&nbsp<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-printer me-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M2.5 8a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1z"/>
            <path d="M5 1a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v2H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v3a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h1v1a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-1h1a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1V3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5zM4 3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h6a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2H4V3zm1 5a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V7a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-1v-1a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5zm7 2v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h6a1 1 0 0 1 1 1z"/>
          </svg>Print &nbsp</button>
        </div>
        <div id="list">
            <!-- <div id="task" class="task">
                <div id="content">
                    <label for="name">Full name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" readonly>
                    <br>
                    <label for="phone">Phone no:</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" readonly>
                    <br>
                    <label for="check-in">Check-in:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="check-in" readonly>
                    <br>
                    <label for="P_Q">Price Quotation:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="P_Q" readonly></input>
                    <br>
                    <label for="device-type">Device type:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="device-type" readonly>
                    <br>
                    <label for="damage">Damage:</label>
                    <textarea id="damage" rows="4" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="actions">
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="/Bootstrap.js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/digital-reference/digital-reference.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest to include also the corresponding html to prevent doing any assumption

Comment: I'd also suggest trying to pair this problem back a bit, and creating a [minimmal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- e.g. what is the smallest amount of code that showcases the problem you're having

Comment: _"I found a way to take just the first reference for printing, but unfortunately, I haven't found a way to print all the references/divs."_ - how about you write them _all_ to the popup window first, and then call the `print` method _after_ the loop, instead of inside it?